# How to create JSON data for a stacked bar chart from react-chartjs2

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2, stacked-bar-chart

I am having this data from api, I want to make a stacked bar chart in reactjs from this data -

```
[{
    "project_id": 1,
    "project_name": "P1",
    "assessment_id": 1,
    "assessment_name": "Assessment 01",
    "maturity": "10"
},

{
    "project_id": 1,
    "project_name": "P1",
    "assessment_id": 2,
    "assessment_name": "Assessment 02",
    "maturity": "40"

}]
```

Pls help me out on this. Thanks!

I went through react-chartjs2 documentation on stacked bar chart but there is nothing much written there,
and particularly for the above JSON data, how can I create a stacked bar chart, I couldnt understand. Pls help me out on this. Thanks!